# I want to access this play button with react.js. I added this video with video tag. And Now I want to set eventhandler on this play icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml

I want to access this play button with react.js. I added this video with video tag. And Now I want to set an event handler on this play icon

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you put some effort into your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The browsers provide built-in controls for the media elements (video and audio). Most players will disable the standard controls and replace them. Here are some suggestions for you:

1. Attach the event handler to the `video` element itself
2. Attach it to one of the media element events
3. Position an transparent element on top of the video element and attach the event handler to it.
4. Replace the video controls with your own. (or use an existing player like video.js)
5. Check and style the controls using Shadow DOM (depends on the browser).