# how to access the play icon on the video player?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml

I want to access this play button with react.js. I added this video with video tag. And Now I want to set eventhandler[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWdBY.png) on this play icon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to access this play button with react.js. I added this video with video tag. And Now I want to set eventhandler on this play icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74142665/i-want-to-access-this-play-button-with-react-js-i-added-this-video-with-video-t)